# java array printing the repeated numbers , array in the array

Tags: java, arrays

Please could you tell me how its work in section  (g[ss[i]]++;) and tell me the sequence of output in java

```
class A{
    public static void main(String []a){
        int []ss={1,2,3,4,2,3,3,1,1,1,5,6,4,5,4};
        int []g=new int[15];
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
            g[ss[i]]++;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<15;i++){
            System.out.println(ss[i-1]+"=="+g[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it, that will give you the output

Comment: Please could you attempt to write this in a more complicated way?

Comment: @RossDrew All this just to print out a series of lies `1==4` indeed

Comment: @Richard Tingle: I guess it should be "1 was found 4 times".  There are a couple of flaws with the code, such as the hard coded 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you run it?

`g[ss[i]]++;` can be rewritten as

```
int index = ss[i];
g[index] = g[index] + 1;
```

So it's counted number of each number in ss.

It's very error prone, and you should never do something like that.

Comment: please could you explain more about g[ss[i]]++; ?

Comment: @user What exactly is unclear? I'v described operation order. One more, maybe a little clearer way may be `g[ss[i]] = g[ss[i]] + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Just run it?

```
1==4
2==2
3==3
4==3
2==2
3==1
3==0
1==0
1==0
1==0
5==0
6==0
4==0
5==0
```

This should be your output.

Comment: thanks for answering . yeah i know how to run it but i just wanted to know how this line worked g[ss[i]]++; @seagull

Comment: thanks for answering . yeah i know how to run it but i just wanted to know how this line worked g[ss[i]]++; @leviathan